# Ansible smtp mail send

Tags: linux, server, ansible, devops, system-administration

I'm trying to send a mail fron Ansible.

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
  - mail:
      host: smtp.gmail.com

      port: 587

      username: ****@gmail.com

      password: *******

      to: John Smith ***@gmail.com

      subject: 'Ansible-report'

      body: 'System  has been successfully provisioned.'

    delegate_to: localhost
```

but I get an error

> fatal: [host1 -> localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed":
>   true, "msg": "Authentication to smtp.gmail.com:587 failed, please
>   check your username and/or password", "rc": 1}

I use the example from the official site http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/mail_module.html

As I understand, SMTP authentication already exists in the source new module ANSIBLE.
File "/tmp/ansible_K94pcN/ansible_module_mail.py", line 304, in main
    smtp.login(username, password)

File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 621, in login
    raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)

> fatal: [host1 -> localhost]: FAILED! => {
>       "changed": false,

```
"failed": true,

"invocation": {

    "module_args": {

        "attach": null,
        "bcc": null,
        "body": "System ubuntu has been successfully provisioned.",
        "cc": null,
        "charset": "us-ascii",
        "headers": null,
        "host": "smtp.gmail.com",
        "password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
        "port": 587,
        "secure": "starttls",
        "sender": "root",
        "subject": "Ansible-report",
        "subtype": "plain",
        "timeout": 20,
        "to": "Cristiano Ross <cristianooross@gmail.com>",
        "username": "victorradin9@gmail.com"
    }
},
"msg": "Authentication to smtp.gmail.com:587 failed, please check your usern              ame and/or password",
"rc": 1
```

Comment: It says "authentication failed". Are you certain you have your gmail credentials correct?  Do those same credentials work if you test them using a diagnostic tool such as [swaks](http://www.jetmore.org/john/code/swaks/) (or when used to configure an email client)? Do you need to enable `secure: starttls` in your playbook?

Comment: @larsks and other, pls see -vvv output , i use starttls, and try with utf-8

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 4):

The issue your facing is an authentication issue caused by using the correct username & password to send email from a Gmail account without an app specific password assigned.

You'll need to:

a) Setup '2 step authentication' for the sender gmail account.

b) Then you'll need to [create an app specific password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en) in your google account settings.

Using that newly generated app specific password you'll be able to send mail just like in the example below

```
   - mail:
     host: smtp.gmail.com
     port: 587
     secure: starttls
     charset: utf-8
     sender: victorradin9@gmail.com
     username: victorradin9@gmail.com
     password: your app password generated by google for you goes here
     to: 'cristianooross@gmail.com'
     subject: Ya u rite
```